# Parsing {{store url=''}} in custom configuration text field in Magento

Tags: php, magento

I've created a custom configuration text field in Magento admin called Link.
Whatever is entered becomes pulled in frontend as URL.
User can add absolute paths and also Magento variable {{store url='awesome.html'}}.

The question is how to pull the {{store url='awesome.html'}} in the frontend to become http://www.domain.com/awesome.html?

[image]

Comment: Refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5892476/how-to-get-data-from-magento-system-configuration

Comment: Thank you, but this doesn't solve my question. My fields are text only fields, and I don't have any Model file.

EDIT: I appropriated the solution from the link and it's working now.

Comment: you have to evalute the value - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6221054/magento-how-do-i-access-custom-variables-in-php

Comment: is that working now !

Answer (score 0):

I used this in the block

```
echo str_replace( '{{store url=""}}', Mage::getBaseUrl(), $top_menu_category->getContent() ); ?>
```

And it works for me in blocks, you need to use that function, because as I see, in template that variables aren't parsed